# How to find SharePoint site root from a link to site content?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

User wants to connect to SharePoint through CSOM. To create `ClientContext` user must pass to it site URL. User ought not be a SharePoint expert. He or she might input a string to some internal site page, list or whatever. How to calculate a valid link to pass to `ClientContext` on creation from an arbitrary link input by user? After context is created, it is fairly easy to find its root through a standard function call. But how to find the root **without** context?

This question is not specific to CSOM. Maybe there is a sort of standard URI parsing or other recipes? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking about managed CSOM. you need to do URL parsing for that you can use below

```
var url = new Uri("https://example.com/sites/test/lists/listname/allitems.aspx");

var array1 [] = url.Segments;
```

array1  will have below value

[0] - "/"

[1] - "sites/"

[2] - "test/"

[3] - "lists/"

[4] - "listname/"

[5] - "allitems.aspx/"

Based on how you SC root url is configured, from above you need to determine that your SC root is in 2nd index, then generate the url accordingly to create client context.

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions. I thought on it but have many doubts on how universal it is. "sites/" looks optional. I remember I was able to create sites right on the root. Besides, there might be sub-sites on many levels. Maybe "lists/" is a universal key? So, to go from end to start, find the segment named "lists/" and then take remaining left part of the URL in a hope that this is what user is looking for? I cant consider it as a complete answer but it is definitely a step in the right direction.